# handle promises in Vuetify data tables

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

I have a problem when trying to insert the response of an API call (I am using axios) into a vue data table. If I manually write an html table like this:

```
<table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th v-for="(item, n) in headers" v-bind:key="n">{{item.text}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr v-for="(item, n) in info" v-bind:key="n">
                <td>{{ item.code }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.symbol }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.rate }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.rate_float }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

the code works and displays some data.
But when I try to use the Vuetify data table like this:

```
<v-data-table
                app
                :headers="headers"
                :items="info"
                class="elevation-2"
        >
            <template v-slot:items="props">
                <td>{{ props.item.code }}</td>
                <td>{{ props.item.symbol }}</td>
                <td>{{ props.item.rate }}</td>
                <td>{{ props.item.description }}</td>
                <td>{{ props.item.rate_float }}</td>
            </template>
        </v-data-table>
```

it gives me the following warning:

```
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:620 [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, got Object 

found in

---> <VDataTable>
       <ApiExample> at src/views/ApiExample.vue
         <VContent>
           <VApp>
             <App> at src/App.vue
               <Root>
```

Leading to this error:

```
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:1887 TypeError: this.items.map is not a function
    at VueComponent.items (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js:21511)
    at Watcher.run (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:4556)
    at flushSchedulerQueue (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:4298)
    at Array.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:1979)
    at flushCallbacks (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:1905)
```

The application works if instead of trying to diplay the dynamic data I try to display a statically defined object ("staticitems"). In my opinion the problem is that the data table is expecting an array but instead it finds a Promise so it crashes. Below is the full code for the application .

```
<template>
    <v-container fluid>
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th v-for="(item, n) in headers" v-bind:key="n">{{item.text}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr v-for="(item, n) in info" v-bind:key="n">
                <td>{{ item.code }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.symbol }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.rate }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.rate_float }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <v-data-table
                app
                :headers="headers"
                :items="info"
                class="elevation-2"
        >
            <template v-slot:items="props">
                <td>{{ props.item.code }}</td>
                <td>{{ props.item.symbol }}</td>
                <td>{{ props.item.rate }}</td>
                <td>{{ props.item.description }}</td>
                <td>{{ props.item.rate_float }}</td>
            </template>
        </v-data-table>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        name: "ApiExample",
        data() {
            return {
                info: [],
                info2: [],
                headers: [
                    {text: 'code', value: 'code'},
                    {text: 'symbol', value: 'symbol'},
                    {text: 'rate', value: 'rate'},
                    {text: 'description', value: 'description'},
                    {text: 'rate_float', value: 'rate_float'},
                ],
                staticitems: [
                    {
                        code: "USD",
                        symbol: "$",
                        rate: "5,247.0417",
                        description: "United States Dollar",
                        rate_float: "5247.0417"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            axios
                .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
                .then(response => (this.info = response.data.bpi))
                .catch(error => console.error(error))
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Give us a sample of your data please that actually come back from the api.

Comment: The api is public you can get the response at this link [link](https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json)

Comment: bpi is an object. Is should be an array.

Comment: yeah you're right but why the first code works then ?

Comment: Short answers: Because there is nothing wrong with looping through Objects using `for-in`. Its just that the `v-data-table` is designed to loop through arrays.

Just sanitize data so its in an array format.

Answer (score 0):

> type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, got Object.

It is what it means. `Datatable` is fine with using data returned from promises as long as the type of response is an `array`. Your promise is returning an `object`.

> The application works if instead of trying to diplay the dynamic data I try to display a statically defined object ("staticitems").

staticitems is not an object. It is an array of object. Arrays are displayed like this: [] and objects like {}

You need to make sure that the response coming back from an API is an array. I created a simple [example](https://codepen.io/djshan/pen/jRRMYr?editors=1010) from your API call to show you the right format of your response. As you can see `info` is now an array and the `datatable` works fine.